# How to use Arrays.asList() method to return a list of objects?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm setting up a RestController using Spring-boot. This project requires me to return a list of object (in this case objects of class Book). How do I do that?

I've tried Arrays.asList() method by passing a object of class Book shown below:

**java**

```
@RestController
public class BookController {

    @GetMapping("/books")
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {

        return Arrays.asList(new Book(1l, "Book name", "Book author"));

    }
}
```

**java**

```
public class Book {

    Long id;
    String name;
    String author;

    public Book(Long id, String name, String author) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", author=" + author + "]";
    }
}
```

I've got this error `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Book>"`. How can I fix this?

Comment: why didn't `Arrays.asList` work?

Comment: What problem with your code? did you get any error or any unexpected result?

Comment: I've got this error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Book>" from the return statement of getAllBooks() method

Comment: the code that you share it seems not throwing this error!

Comment: Adding `import java.util.*;` and commenting out the jpa annotation makes it compile fine with `javac -Xlint:all *.java`. (Also, use `List.of` since Java SE 9.)

Comment: Not sure what you have missed, possibly just the import is missing ? have a look to this Demo : https://onlinegdb.com/SJf9MKqRV   what is your Java version ?

Comment: Thanks all, the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It happened to me several times, and the reason was always that IDE somehow auto imported other Arrays class, from junit package, not the one from java.util.
So check your imports part and put `import java.util.Arrays;` if another Arrays class is imported instead. 
@Tom Hawtin - tackline suggested similar, but nothing else is needed except correct import.